Como restringir o acesso do evento àpenas a ul selecionada em uma lista de uls com o mesmo class?


$(document).on('blur', "ul.notes input[type=number]", function() { 

// Identifica a lista atual onde ocorreu o evento
const currentList = $(this).closest("ul.notes");

// Obtém o ID do estudante
const student_id = $(this).attr("name").match(/\[(\d+)\]/)[1];

ad1 = $("input[name='ad1[" + student_id + "]']")
ap1 = $("input[name='ap1[" + student_id + "]']")
ad2 = $("input[name='ad2[" + student_id + "]']")
ap2 = $("input[name='ap2[" + student_id + "]']")
ap3 = $("input[name='ap3[" + student_id + "]']")
ap4 = $("input[name='ap4[" + student_id + "]']")

sum1 = (Number(ad1.val()) + Number(ap1.val())).toFixed(2);
sum2 = (Number(ad2.val()) + Number(ap2.val())).toFixed(2);
sum = ( ( sum1 + sum2 ) / 2 ).toFixed(2);

console.log(sum1)
console.log(sum2)
console.log(sum1+sum2)
console.log(sum)

if ( $(this).is(ad1) || $(this).is(ap1) ) 
    $(this).parent().parent().find("label.n1").html(sum1);

if ( $(this).is(ad2) || $(this).is(ap2) ) 
    $(this).parent().parent().find("label.n2").html(sum2);

$(this).parent().parent().find("label.n3").html(sum);

});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list">
    <ul class="notes">
      <li style="width: 250px"><label>Nome: </label><input type="hidden" name="students[281]">Fulano</li>
      <li class="li120"><label>AD1: </label><input type="number" name="ad1[281]" value="0.00"></li>
      <li class="li120"><label>AP1: </label><input type="number" name="ap1[281]" value="0.00"></li>
      <li class="li120"><label>N1: </label><label class="n1">0.00</label></li>
      <li class="li120"><label>AD2: </label><input type="number" name="ad2[281]" value="0.00"></li>
      <li class="li120"><label>AP2: </label><input type="number" name="ap2[281]" value="0.00"></li>
      <li class="li120"><label>N2: </label><label class="n2">0.00</label></li>
      <li class="li120"><label>MÉDIA: </label><label class="n3">0.00</label></li>
      <li class="li120"><label>AP3: </label><input type="number" name="ap3[281]" value="0.00"></li>
      <li class="li120"><label>AP4: </label><input type="number" name="ap4[281]" value="0.00"></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="notes">
      <li style="width: 250px"><label>Nome: </label><input type="hidden" name="students[352]">Bertano</li>
      <li class="li120"><label>AD1: </label><input type="number" name="ad1[352]" value="0.00"></li>
      <li class="li120"><label>AP1: </label><input type="number" name="ap1[352]" value="0.00"></li>
      <li class="li120"><label>N1: </label><label class="n1">0.00</label></li>
      <li class="li120"><label>AD2: </label><input type="number" name="ad2[352]" value="0.00"></li>
      <li class="li120"><label>AP2: </label><input type="number" name="ap2[352]" value="0.00"></li>
      <li class="li120"><label>N2: </label><label class="n2">0.00</label></li>
      <li class="li120"><label>MÉDIA: </label><label class="n3">0.00</label></li>
      <li class="li120"><label>AP3: </label><input type="number" name="ap3[352]" value="0.00"></li>
      <li class="li120"><label>AP4: </label><input type="number" name="ap4[352]" value="0.00"></li>
   </ul>
</div>



O objetivo é que ao clicar em uma LI de uma determinada UL**,** apenas o conteúdo dessa UL seja tratado.
Por exemplo: ao editar o input text primeiro e sair dele, somar seu conteudo ao segundo input text e colocar o resultado da soma no label com class=n1 QUE esta na mesma coluna.
Analogamente, fazer o mesmo com os input text segundo.
Continuando na mesma linha, repetir o processo, só que desta vez envovendo apenas os inputs nth(3) e nth(4) e o resultado da soma ir para o label class=n2
Esse processo se repete separadamente para cada linha,
Mas a conta não esta funcionando corretamente para os console.logs pois as saidas estão sendo as seguintes:
35.00
0.00
35.000.00
NaN
109.00
0.00
109.000.00
NaN
109.00
32.00
109.0032.00
NaN
109.00
118.00  
109.00118.00
NaN
109.00
118.00
109.00118.00
NaN


Os comentários foram movidos para o chat. Por favor, continuem no chat. Para continuarmos é importante ler e compreender a finalidade do site, então [edit] a pergunta e trocar o código fornecido por um [mcve] do problema, de forma a facilitar a identificação e servir como referência para futuros visitantes. Agradecemos a compreensão.
